# WMS server side playlist driving me crazy, any thoughts?

Tags: windows-server-2008, video-streaming, windows

I have been working on setting up video streaming for employees from a website over http via Windows Media Services on Windows server 2008.

I have almost everything working the way I want but can't, for the life of me, figure out how to display items in Media Player to stream.

Here is the situation so far:

- Streaming internally over mms/http works but **no playlist** (both .asx/.wsx)
- Streaming externally over mms/http works but **no playlist** (both .asx/.wsx)
- Streaming locally with .asx works
- Streaming on the server itself with .asx works
- Streaming internally using UNC path works and displays playslist (it is the only way I have gotten it to show up and how it looks in the pic below.  This is with .asx)

[image]

From what I have read, there should be a way to get this same playlist effect using the .wsx server side playlist feature in WMS but it is driving me crazy and google has failed me.

Here is what my semi functional .wsx file looks like so far, but again no right side playlist shows up with this:

```
<?wsx version="1.0"?>
<smil>
<seq>

<media src="Dental benefits 2011.wmv" mediaName="Dental">
<clientData title="Dental Benefits"/>
</media>

    <media src="Benefits Meeting Nov 2011 2.wmv" mediaName="Benefits">
<clientData title="Benefits Meeting"/>
</media>

    <media src="FSA 2011 presentation.wmv" mediaName="FSA">
<clientData title="FSA Presentation"/>
</media>

    <media src="Walk .wmv" mediaName="Walk">
<clientData title="Walk"/>
</media>

</seq>
</smil>
```

I have no real background in media streaming so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I might be barking up the wrong tree here, I found these links saying that it is not possible to publish remote playlists in WMP. http://www.winvistatips.com/wpl-asx-m3u-dont-show-their-inividual-files-playlist-t500494.html and http://www.winvistatips.com/asx-files-behavior-different-between-local-file-and-served-up-t211911.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link and don't think I am going to try digging any further into this issue.  From the reading I have done, there is a security issue and that is why what I am trying is not possible.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;837170#appliesto

**EDIT:**  I spoke with a Microsoft engineer confirming that this behavior is done intentionally, so I will be able to sleep a little better now.